# How to get a letter from an element in a list

Tags: list, function, python-3.x

So I have some homework where it says that I have a list and if there is a vowel in the beginning and the last letter in each element of a list, I have to get those vowels in a string. So for example:

```
["Roberto", "Jessie", "A", "Geoffrey", "Eli"]
```

turns into

```
oeaei
```

So far I have this code:

```
vowels = "aeiou"
new_list = []
for words in a_list:
    a_list = [words.lower() for words in a_list]
for letters in vowels:
    if a_list[0] == vowels or a_list[-1] == vowels:
        new_list += a_list[vowels]
return new_list
```

But I get the error

```
[]
[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Miraj\Desktop\Q3.py", line 27, in <module>
test_get_first_last_vowels()
File "C:\Users\Miraj\Desktop\Q3.py", line 24, in test_get_first_last_vowels
print(get_first_last_vowels([]))
File "C:\Users\Miraj\Desktop\Q3.py", line 17, in get_first_last_vowels
if a_list[0] == vowels or a_list[-1] == vowels:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

So can I get some help where I'm going wrong. Thank you.

Okay

```
a_list = ["Roberto", "Jessie", "A", "Geoffrey", "Eli"]
```

Comment: Is `a_list = ["Roberto", "Jessie", "A", "Geoffrey", "Eli"]` ?

Comment: If the indices `0` and `-1` are out of range, the list is empty.

Comment: @Idos yes it is sorry for not adding that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
    a_list = ["Roberto", "Jessie", "A", "Geoffrey", "Eli"]

    def start_end_vowels(a_list):
        vowels = "aeiou"
        result = ""

        for words in a_list:
            words = words.lower()

            for vowel in vowels:

                if len(words) == 1:

                    if words == vowel:
                        result += vowel

                else:

                    if words.startswith(vowel):
                        result += vowel

                    if words.endswith(vowel):
                        result += vowel
        return result

        # Output

        >>> a_list = ["Roberto", "Jessie", "A", "Geoffrey", "Eli"]
        >>> start_end_vowels(a_list)
        'oeaei'

        >>> a_list = ["Abba"]
        >>> start_end_vowels(a_list)
        'aa'
```

This does work for your example, but I would double check with other test cases to be sure. It's good to know how to do this sort of question different ways.

Update: edited it to work for cases where starting vowel and ending vowel are the same.

Comment: This does not work for the name `Abba`. It should b `aa` but it finds only `a`.

Comment: @R. Mercy, what are the requirements for having a word that starts with a vowel and ends with a vowel? Must it print both occurrences?

Comment: Fixed @Mike Müller

Answer (score 1):

You are working on an empty list. Further, this will never work:

```
>>> new_list += a_list[vowels]
```

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Since `vowels` is a string, not an integer. You want to use [`append()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_append.htm).

You are also checking the wrong condition:

```
if a_list[0] == vowels or a_list[-1] == vowels:
```

Should be:

```
if a_list[0] == letters or a_list[-1] == letters:
```

This needs to be executed for **every word** in `a_list`, so make sure it is inside the loop and not stand-alone.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
def find_vowels(a_list):
    vowels = set('aeiou')
    res = []
    for word in a_list:
        if not word:
            continue
        word = word.lower()
        if word[0] in vowels:
            res.append(word[0])
        if len(word) > 1 and word[-1] in vowels:
            res.append(word[-1])
    return ''.join(res)
```

Now:

```
>>> a_list = ["Roberto", "Jessie", "A", "Geoffrey", "Eli"]
>>> find_vowels(a_list)
'oeaei'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has several flaws in the light of what you are trying to do , like you need not write

```
for words in a_list:
```

when you have written

```
a_list = [words.lower() for words in a_list]
```

the looping over all words is done by the second line alone.

Also when you say

```
if a_list[0] == vowels or a_list[-1] == vowels:
```

then `a_list[0]` or `a_list[-1]` is matched with the whole string `'aeiou'`, which will never be true. You need to match `a_list[0]` or `a_list[-1]` with individual vowels.

And lastly as @Idos said,

```
new_list += a_list[vowels]
```

this line is not going to work.

So I have written a fresh code taking all these into account and also considering the special case, if the word is a singe letter one. The code is given below

```
a_list = ["Roberto", "Jessie", "A", "Geoffrey", "Eli"]
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
new_list = []
for word in a_list:
    if len(word)>=2:
        if word[0].lower() in vowels:
            new_list.append(word[0].lower())
        if word[-1].lower() in vowels:
            new_list.append(word[-1].lower())
    elif len(word)==1:
        if word.lower() in vowels:
            new_list.append(word.lower())
print (''.join(new_list))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can employ listcomps or genexps to write a succinct program as follows. It has **3 lines and reads like English**.

```
vowels = 'aeiou'
# collect
groups = (word if len(word) == 1 else (word[0], word[-1]) for word in words)
# flatten and filter
chars = (char for group in groups for char in group if char.lower() in vowels)
# consume the iterator
''.join(chars) # 'oeAEi'
```